# python scrappy football data

Tags: python, css

i am trying to learn how to use scrappy with python; i am not familiar with css

the website i am trying to scrape: https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/point-spreads-and-odds?season=2018&seasontype=1&week=17

so when i copy the selector for the date, this is the result:

## stats_grid > div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > span

when I bring up the scrappy module by doing: python shell "url"

and type in response.css('selector here')

I get no results!

How do i retrieve the date information?

Thanks for reading this message!

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that the data you're trying to scrape is not available when scrappy receives the page response.

If you have your browser's developer console open when the page loads, check out the XHR request on the network tab to this URL:

`https://fantasydata.com/NFLTeamStats/Odds_Read`

If you check out its payload, you'll see that it contains exactly the data you are trying to scrape. In other words, it's loaded from the site's app via an HTTP fetch *AFTER* the initial page has loaded.

So, when you use a webscaper (like scrappy), you're unable to see that kind of data. You really only get the initial page template, and anything loaded by javascript after is unavailable.

If you're looking for general NFL and fantasy related stats, there's an app called FFDB that allows you to easily create databases using its engine:

[FFDB Github Repository](https://github.com/rushfive/FFDB)

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the app.*

As a last note, be aware that a `css` tag is not relevant for this issue. A `scraping` or `webscrape` tag would be more appropriate.

Best of luck!